# SSRS report fails to load in browser report manager - rsFilterEvaluationError

Tags: reporting-services

The ssrs report uses a filter in the tablix properties. 
The report is successfully generated in the visual studio preview but when i try to generate the preview in browser (chrome, IE) via the reporting manager, i receive the following error.

> Failed to evaluate the FilterExpression Tablix "Tablix2". (rsFilterEvaluationError)

Might not be the 100% correct error message bc i got them in german.

Expression (date type): `=Cdate(Format(CDate(Right(Trim(Fields!CustomerReqDate.Value),2) & "." & Mid(Trim(Fields!CustomerReqDate.Value),5,2) & "." & Left(Trim(Fields!CustomerReqDate.Value), 4)), "dd.MM.yyyy"))`

Operator: <=

Value: `=Cdate(Format(DateAdd("d",42,Now), "dd.MM.yyyy"))`

Comment: Please show the expression you're using as well as the settings in the Filters tab (like the operator and data type you selected).

Comment: @StevenWhite please see my updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it works in preview but not the browser it may have to do with localization settings. I'm assuming CustomerReqDate is a string in the form of "YYYYMMDD". Try using this expression instead:

```
=DateSerial(Left(Trim(Fields!CustomerReqDate.Value), 4)
    , Mid(Trim(Fields!CustomerReqDate.Value),5,2)
    , Right(Trim(Fields!CustomerReqDate.Value),2))
```

And just use the DateAdd function, don't worry about formatting and conversions.

```
=DateAdd("d",42,Now)
```

This should allow SSRS to compare a date to a date regardless of the local format.